# Updating QPixmap crashes application in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qpixmap

In the code below, when I load the GridscanCanvas' pixmap with the function get_core_data it works perfectly fine, no crashes, and the image is then displayed in my app.

However, when I want to update that same pixmap in the function get_square_data, it crashes every time.

Both times, the original image is an np.array and the only difference between them is the size of the array. I've commented on the code where it crashes.

I'm very lost, since both functions are nearly identical. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

import os
import numpy as np
from mdoc_class import Gridscan_mdoc
from mrc_class import Gridscan_mrc
from em_ss_find_gridsquares import find_gridsquares



class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setGeometry(100,100,1000,1000)
        self.main_widget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.main_widget)
        self.gridscan_canvas = GridscanCanvas(self)
        self.init_menu()

        self.pixel_size = 92.7
        self.gridsquare_length = 85000
        self.spacing_length = 40000

        self.show()


    def init_menu(self):
        bar = self.menuBar()
        self.file = bar.addMenu('File')
        load_mdoc_action = QAction('Load mdoc', self)
        self.file.addAction(load_mdoc_action)
        self.file.triggered.connect(self.file_respond)
        find_squares_action = QAction('Find squares', self)
        self.file.addAction(find_squares_action)



    def file_respond(self, q):
        signal = q.text()
        if signal == 'Load mdoc':
            mdoc_file = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open File', os.getenv('Home'),
                                                    "MDOC(*.mdoc);;AllFiles(*.*)")[0]
            if mdoc_file:
                try:
                    self.load_core_data = LoadCoreData(mdoc_file)
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
                    return
                try:
                    self.load_core_data.new_output.connect(self.get_core_data)
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
                    return
                try:
                    self.load_core_data.start()
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
                    return

        elif signal == 'Find squares':
            try:
                self.find_squares = FindGridsquares(self.mrc.gridscan, self.pixel_size, self.gridsquare_length,
                                                    self.spacing_length)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                return
            try:
                self.find_squares.new_output.connect(self.get_square_data)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                return
            try:
                self.find_squares.start()
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                return
        else:
            return


    def get_core_data(self, core_data):
        self.mrc = core_data['mrc']
        self.mdoc = core_data['mdoc']

        # This here works fine
        self.gridscan_canvas.pixmap = QPixmap(QImage(self.mrc.gridscan, self.mrc.gridscan.shape[1],
                                                     self.mrc.gridscan.shape[0], QImage.Format_Grayscale8))
        self.gridscan_canvas.update()

    def get_square_data(self, square_data):
        self.centres = square_data['centres']
        self.aligned_centres = square_data['aligned_centres']
        self.aligned_gridscan = square_data['aligned_gridscan']
        self.rot_angle = square_data['rot_angle']
        self.sqrd_centres = square_data['sqrd_centres']

        # This here crashes is where it crashes
        self.gridscan_canvas.pixmap = QPixmap(QImage(self.aligned_gridscan, self.aligned_gridscan.shape[1],
                                                     self.aligned_gridscan.shape[0], QImage.Format_Grayscale8))
        self.gridscan_canvas.update()


class GridscanCanvas(QWidget):
    DELTA  = 10
    def __init__(self,  *args, **kwargs):
        super(GridscanCanvas, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.draggin_idx = -1
        self.points_old = np.array([[v * 5, v * 5] for v in range(75)], dtype=np.float)
        self.width = 700
        self.height = 700
        self.setFixedSize(self.width, self.height)
        self.pixmap = None

        self.points = None
        self.scaling_factor = [1, 1]

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        qp = QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        if self.pixmap is not None:
            self.pixmap = self.pixmap.scaled(self.width, self.height, transformMode=Qt.SmoothTransformation)
            qp.drawPixmap(0, 0, self.width, self.height, self.pixmap)
        else:
            self.scaling_factor = [1, 1]
        if self.points is not None:
            self.drawPoints(qp)
        qp.end()

    def drawPoints(self, qp):
        pen = QPen()
        pen.setWidth(5)
        pen.setColor(Qt.red)
        qp.setPen(pen)

        for x,y in self.points:
            qp.drawPoint(x,y)


class LoadCoreData(QThread):
    new_output = pyqtSignal(object)

    def __init__(self, mdoc_filepath):
        QThread.__init__(self)
        self.isRunning = True
        self.mdoc_filepath = mdoc_filepath

    def __del__(self):
        self.wait()

    def run(self):
        mdoc = Gridscan_mdoc(self.mdoc_filepath)
        mrc = Gridscan_mrc(mdoc)
        output = {'mdoc': mdoc, 'mrc': mrc}
        self.new_output.emit(output)


class FindGridsquares(QThread):
    new_output = pyqtSignal(object)

    def __init__(self, gridscan, pixel_size, gridsquare_length, spacing_length):
        QThread.__init__(self)
        self.isRunning = True
        self.gridscan = gridscan
        self.pixel_size = pixel_size
        self.gridsquare_length = gridsquare_length
        self.spacing_length = spacing_length

    def __del__(self):
        self.wait()

    def run(self):
        centres, aligned_centres, aligned_gridscan, rot_angle, sqrd_centres =find_gridsquares(self.gridscan, self.pixel_size, self.gridsquare_length, self.spacing_length)
        output = {'centres': centres, 'aligned_centres': aligned_centres, 'aligned_gridscan': aligned_gridscan, 'rot_angle': rot_angle, 'sqrd_centres': sqrd_centres}
        self.new_output.emit(output)



app = QApplication([])
window = MainWindow()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: what is `em_ss_find_gridsquares`? What library does it belong to?

Comment: em_ss_find_gridsquares is my own functions. It works no problem, and returns the files as expected. The only problem arises when I'm trying to update the pixmap for the second time. Both times format of the images is identical, with the only exception being the size of the image (the difference in size is about 1%)

Comment: mmm, is that function relevant? If not, then delete it from the code you are showing, please provide a [mcve], if we can not reproduce your problem it will be impossible for us to help you

Comment: yes, it's a very important function. I'll try to recreate the problem in a more simplified way!

Comment: If it is important then you must show it in your question, have you read the meaning of a [mcve]?